# Difference between floor function and floor division

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is the answer not same for the below operations, and also, since `//` is essentially floor division, then why is the output different when a floor function is used.

I ran the following code:

```
import math
x = 2**64 -1
print("Original value:", x)
print("Floor division:", x//1)
print("Floor function:", math.floor(x/1))
print("Trunc function:", math.trunc(x/1))
print("Type conversion:", int((x/1)))
```

Output:

```
Original value: 18446744073709551615
Floor division: 18446744073709551615
Floor function: 18446744073709551616
Trunc function: 18446744073709551616
Type conversion: 18446744073709551616
```

Now, why is the answer not equal to the original value since all i did was divide by 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`float` is a 64 bit IEEE-754 binary floating point value; it only has 53 bits of integer precision (beyond which it's stuck with imprecise approximations based on multiplying an integer value by a power of 2), and you put a 64 bit value in there when you divided by `1` (which coerced to a `float` result before the eventual call to `round`/`trunc`). Basically, it made the `float` value as close to the `int` you used as possible, which was unfortunately not equal to the `int` (because that's impossible), then rounded/truncated it (which, given the value had no decimal component, just meant converting back to the equivalent `int` value).

Floor division with `//` never has the problem, because it's a purely `int`-based division (nothing is ever represented as a `float`), and `int`s are (to the limits of computer memory) effectively infinite precision.

Comment: Also note that the problem should occur only for odd values of x, due to python's tendency to round to nearest even. There shouldn't be an error in OP's operation if x is even.

Comment: @Mercury: That's the case for rounding off the last `5` in a number (when it's a "real 5", not actually `49999999993` or some other imprecise representation). For numbers larger than `float`'s maximum representable integer, the problem occurs for progressively larger ranges of numbers where each range covers the span of some power of 2. In this case, there are ~2048 numbers that will all become `18446744073709551616` when divided by `1` (half of them above that number, the other half below it).

Comment: Follow-up correction: There are actually 3073 `int`s that become `2**64` when converted to `float`, starting at `2**64 - 1024` and continuing through `2**64 + 2048`. Normally it's a power of two range, but in this case, we crossed a power of two boundary so the range is twice as high above the limit (the representation limits of `float` are even worse at that point).

Answer (score 5):

`/` converts to float. And float arithmetic has inherent numerical errors. As soon as you input `x/1` you potentially introduce errors on the original value of `x`. Once the error is there you basically can't recover it.

This is broader than just an integer flooring issue:

```
x = 2**70 + 123
print(x-int(x/1))

123
```

Comment: ohh my god, your example shook my mind. The error gap is wide.

Answer (score 0):

Conversions to integer can unmask inaccuracies in a floating-point number. For example, the closest single-precision floating-point number to 21.33 is slightly less than 21.33, so when it is multiplied by 100, the result Y is slightly less than 2133.0.

If you print Y in a typical floating-point format, rounding causes it to be displayed as 2133.00. However, if you assign Y to an integer I, no rounding is done, and the number is truncated to 2132.

Also, as @shadowRanger said, `//` represents integer division and hence is precise till infinite.